# Does anyone know where or how I get the VMWare Visual Studio Plugin 'installed'?

Tags: visual-studio, vmware

I have read a number of blogs talking about this VMware Visual Studio Plugin that supposedly has been out since VS 2005.  But I can't find a single reference to how to install, activate, enable....etc.

I am using VS2010, but have also looked in 2008.  I am new to VS to begin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From their installation manual:

If Visual Studio is already installed on your host, the VMware Workstation installer should also install the
Integrated Virtual Debugger.

- If you install Workstation after you install Visual Studio, you can choose custom install to verify that
  Integrated Virtual Debuggers > Visual Studio PlugIn is selected.
- If you install Visual Studio after you install Workstation, run the Workstation installer again.

  - a In the program maintenance dialog box, select Modify/Change.
  - b To install, click Integrated Virtual Debuggers > Visual Studio PlugIn and proceed.

Source: http://www.vmware.com/pdf/ws7_visualstudio_debug.pdf

Comment: Actually, the problem is that in all the blogs I read that talked about this (including the main "Official VMWare Workstation Blog" never mentions that you can't be on a VM as your development environment.  It requires the local running VS to be on the VMWare host.  So this would actually explain why I could never see the "VMware" tab.